# Is the conductor of an L-function F the absolute value of the discriminant ofsome number field related to F?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, algebraic-number-theory, l-functions

In the theory of automorphic forms, ramified primes of an L-function divide the so-called conductor thereof. On the other hand, one can define for a number field  $ K $ an integral invariant  $ \Delta_{K} $ equal to the square of the determinant of some square matrix defined through a basis of the ring of integers  $ O_{K} $ and complex embeddings.
It appears that the conductor of the Dedekind zeta function of a number field  $ K $ is  $ \vert \Delta_{K}\vert $.

Hence my question  : is it possible for any L-function  $ F $ to define a related number field whose absolute value of the discriminant is the conductor of  $ F $? If yes, how is it defined ?

Comment: Class field theory and Hecke characters are a way to construct tower of abelian extensions with arbitrary ramified primes. Now there is truly a number field only for L-functions arising from Artin L-functions, that is a representation of $Gal(\overline{Q}/Q)$ in the Galois module $O_K$. Elliptic curves and jacobian of curves are over kind of Galois modules.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a description of the considered number field in terms of the Satake parameters  $ \alpha_{j}(p) $ of  $ F $ when  $ p $ runs among unramified primes ?

Comment: Do you see how the Dedekind zeta function of $K= \mathbb{Q}[x]/(f(x)),f \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ basically tells the factorization type of $f$ in every $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$. Conversely given the factorization types of a degree $n$ polynomial you can construct a sequence of polynomials $f_j(x) = f_{j-1}(x)+\prod_{l \le j-1}p_j h_j (x)$ whose factorization type coincides for the primes $p_i,i \le j$. What happens as $j \to \infty$ if you fix an order in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ and pick for every $j$ the least such $f_j$ ?

Comment: I meant an order in $\{ g \in \mathbb{Z}[x], \deg(g) = n\}$ induced by an enumeration so any polynomial has finitely many $<$

Comment: In answer to your actual question; no, not really, in the sense that just because you have an $L$-function with some conductor does not mean that there need be any relation between this $L$-function and some number field with discriminant equal to that conductor.

Comment: But does the compositum of the number fields  $ K_{p}(F)=Q(\{\alpha_{j}(p)\}) $ provide some relevant information on  $ F $?

Comment: After all, the local factor  $ F_{p}(s) $ should be invariant under the action of  $ Aut(K_{p}(F)/Q) $ .

Comment: @PeterHumphries Would you have a few hints on "finding an L-function not being an Artin L-function of a number field" ?  For an Artin L-function, there are finitely many different Euler factors (as rational functions in $p^{-s}$). L functions of elliptic curves with CM are Artin L-functions. So pick an elliptic curve without complex multiplication and use [Sato-Tate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sato%E2%80%93Tate_conjecture) to show it isn't an Artin L-function. Is there a modular form for which Sato-Tate is easily seen to hold ? Wiki's article suggests no.

Comment: @reuns Maass forms.

Comment: @PeterHumphries Do you suggest to look at $n$th symmetric power L-functions of a Maass eigenform ? (also $L(s,\psi, \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3}))$ should come from a Maass form and an Artin L-function)

Comment: @reuns, even $2$-dimensional Maass forms have to have Laplacian eigenvalue $1/4$, whereas almost all Maass forms do not.

Comment: @PeterHumphries What about $L(s,\psi)$ where $\psi(a+ib)  = \frac{(a+ib)^2}{(a-ib)^2}$ is the infinite character on $\mathbb{Z}[i]$. $\sum_{a,b} \psi(a+ib) e^{2i\pi (a^2+b^2)z}$ is a modular form and $L(s,\psi)$ is not an Artin L-function because $|\psi| = 1$ and $\psi$ takes infinitely many values so there is no $N$ such that the roots of all its Euler polynomials are $N$-th roots of unity (that is not of the form $\det(I-\rho(\sigma_p) X), \rho(\sigma_p)^N = I$). Is the abelian variety and Galois representation of that modular form well known ?

Comment: (The modular form is $\sum_{a,b} \psi(a+ib)(a^2+b^2) e^{2i\pi (a^2+b^2)z}=\sum_{a,b} (a+ib)^4 e^{2i\pi (a^2+b^2)z}$ by the Poisson summation formula and that $(x\pm iy)^4 e^{-\pi (x^2+y^2)}$ is its own Fourier transform. Is it a cusp form ?)

Comment: @reuns, these are known as "dihedral" or "monomial" or "CM" cusp forms (in fact, I have a couple of papers on them). Yes, the Galois rep is well-known - I think Ribet has a very nice paper on CM-modular forms and Galois reps.

Answer (score 1):

$\ $ There is a terribly ineffective procedure for Dedekind and Artin L-functions, but it is worth looking at it anyway:

For $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^N a_n x^n \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$, let $v(f) = (N,\sum_{n=0}^{N} |a_n|, a_0,\ldots,a_N,0,\ldots) \in \mathbb{Z}^{\infty}$. Applying the lexical order to $v(f)$ we obtain an order on the integer polynomials satisfying the finite descending chain condition.

Then assume we are given the Euler product of a Dedekind zeta function $\zeta(K,s)=\prod_p\zeta_p(K,s)$ with $K$ an unknown number field.

Pick a primitive element $\alpha$ ($K = \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$) and let $h \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ be its minimal polynomial.

> For $n=1,2,3,\ldots\ $ find the least irreducible polynomial $f_n \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ satisfying $$\forall p \le n, \qquad \zeta_p(\mathbb{Q}[x]/(f_n),s)=\zeta_p(K,s)$$

The sequence $f_n$ is increasing in the order on monic polynomials, and it is bounded above by $h$.

Thus $f_n$ converges, to a polynomial $f$ satisfying $$\zeta(\mathbb{Q}[x]/(f),s)=\zeta(K,s)$$

Do you think $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(f)$ and $ K$ [are isomorphic](https://mathoverflow.net/a/80439/84768) ? What if $K/\mathbb{Q}$ is Galois ?

> For $L(s,\rho,K)$ an Artin L-function, the idea is the same, comparing the factors of $L(s,\rho,K)$ with that of each Artin L-function $L(s,\psi,\mathbb{Q}[x]/(f_n))$.

Restricting to $f_n$ irreducible is for simplicity. If $f_n$ isn't irreducible then $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(f_n(x))$ isn't a field and its ring of integers is ill-defined. But we can still look at the ring structure of $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(f_n(x),p)$ to create (for the $p$ where $f_n$ has $N$ distinct roots) an Euler factor and compare it with $\zeta_p(K,s)$, obtaining that $f_n$ converges to a polynomial $f$ satisfying $\zeta_p(K,s) = \zeta_p(\mathbb{Z}[x]/(f),s)$ for every $p$ unramified in $O_K$ and $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(f)$.

---

2nd part : proving that some L-functions are not Artin L-functions. A conjecture predicts automorphic L-functions $= $ motivic L-functions.

Comment: The "Satake parameters" (the roots of the denominator of L-factors) of Artin L-functions are $n$th roots of unity so its $n$th symmetric power L-function has a pole at $s=1$. [This p.8](https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~michael.harris/Clay.pdf) suggests that if the symmetric powers of an (automorphic ?) L-function never have a pole at $s=1$ then it is not an Artin L-function (and if the PNT holds for those then Sato-Tate's conjecture holds).